# Unexpected NullPointerException using Javassist

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, javassist

I run the following code :

```
    CfField f = ...
    CtClass classeEnglobante = f.getDeclaringClass();
    ClassPool pool = classeEnglobante.getClassPool();
    ConstPool constPool = classeEnglobante.getClassFile().getConstPool();

    AnnotationsAttribute attr = new AnnotationsAttribute(constPool , AnnotationsAttribute.visibleTag);
    Annotation a = new Annotation(constPool, pool.get("org.hibernate.annotations.Index"));
    a.addMemberValue("name", new StringMemberValue("idx_" + p.getNomMinuscule(), constPool));
    attr.addAnnotation(a); // Here is the line 245
```

And this NPE is raised :

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javassist.bytecode.annotation.ArrayMemberValue.write(ArrayMemberValue.java:132)
    at javassist.bytecode.annotation.Annotation.write(Annotation.java:317)
    at javassist.bytecode.AnnotationsAttribute.setAnnotations(AnnotationsAttribute.java:246)
    at com.mycompany.MyClass (MyClass.java:245)
```

Comment: Which line is 245?  Have you checked with a debugger to see whether e.g. `constPool` is `null`?

Comment: @Oli I have edited my post to reflect the line 245

Comment: If `attr.addAnnotation(a);` is the line 245, seems that attr is null or a is null. Check them with a debugger

Comment: I have checked attr and a are not null.

Comment: do you have access to addAnnotation method, so we can see the source code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3028304/363573) solves my problem. 
For some reason there's a bug in javassist 3.1.2.GA.
So here is my error and the solution to it :

**WRONG : Prone to bug**

```
Annotation a = new Annotation(constPool, pool.get("org.hibernate.annotations.Index"));
```

**CORRECT : No bug**

```
Annotation a = new Annotation("org.hibernate.annotations.Index", constPool);
```